# SQL server 2012 - Difference between point in time and complete?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

So i have read Microsoft etc and am struggling to understand the difference in Point in time recovery and complete recovery (i.e. seems to do the same thing, slightly differently).

I.e. when should i use one as opposed to the other, from what i can see i should always use point in time if i have a full backup model?.

Answer (score 0):

Point in time recovery is where you wanted to restore database to specific time of the date, for example some records accidentally deleted at 3:45PM from database and log backup runs every 30 minutes, this is where you can restore database to 3:45PM using Log backups and STOPAT.

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK' 
WITH NORECOVERY
GO 
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.TRN' 
WITH RECOVERY, 
STOPAT = 'Mar 01, 2017 03:45:00 PM' 
GO

Whereby complete recovery is something you can recover database from backups (full/differential) to the last or specific date/time log backup.